# what tags are allowed as grid elements

Tags: css, css-grid

this is a standard grid concept:

```
.wrap{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

<div class='wrap'>
<div class='el'>lorem</div>
<div class='el'>ipsum</div>
<div class='el'>dolor</div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
<div class='wrap'>
<img class='el' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='el' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='el' src='...' alt='img'>
</div>
```

And seems it works - images as grid elements

So my question is - what else can I use as grid elements - `inputs, forms, video...`

I suppose there are some restrictions but can't find any specification regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Never rendered svg elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/render.html#TermNeverRenderedElement) cannot be used as grid items for sure.

Other descendants of `<svg>` elements also probably can't be used, though I can't find any spec on those.

For HTML elements, pretty much anything works as a grid item if you force it to generate a CSS box.

Comment: ` if you force it to generate a CSS box` - pls explain

Comment: Grid items aren't elements, they're boxes. Elements that are by default `display:none` such as head, style, script, etc generate no boxes and therefore in their default state won't make a grid item. Apply e.g. `display:block` to them, and they will generate a box, and that box can be a grid item.